# geometric margin derivation with unit vector?

Tags: svm

In the following graph I would like to obtain the point B:

[image]

According to the author this B is equal to:

[image]

The question that I have is how the author obtain that result. It says that in A is a point x_(i), so I suppose that he projects A onto the unit vector w; and because B can be any point on the hyperplane he uses Euclidean distance to perform its calculations; something like:

```
B=A-dist(A,B)

B=x_(i)-Y_(i).w/||w||
```

Is that ok? but I am not quite sure why he multiply the value of Y_(i) with the unit vector, why is that?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is because dist(A,B) is a scalar. What you need is a vectorial operation to infer the position of a point from another point in the space, so:

```
point(A) - Vector(W) = point(B)
```

Therefore, you need to convert the scalar "dist(A,B)" with the magnitude |dist(A,B)|, into a vector, with the direction of W to be able to perform the operation above.

Therefore, Vector(W) above would become:

```
Vector(W) = dist(A,B) * unitVector(W)
```

Leading to the equation proposed by the author.

Please let me know if this is clear enough.